# Entity Framework Slow Closing Connection

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, database-connection, c#-5.0

I am builing an MVC 5 web app and I am using entity framework 6 and I have MS SQL Server 2008 R2 as my database. I use connection pooling to ensure that I get a connection as fast as possible for db operations. My connection string in my Web.config is as follows

```
<add name="MyConnectionPoolConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=MyHOST;Initial Catalog=TEST_DB;User Id=sa;Password=password1; Min Pool Size=10;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I notice that  obtaining a connection from the connection pool is very  fast i.e. some tens to hundreds of milliseconds

However, what I have also noticed is that closing the connection (which in a connection pool means the connection is returned to the pool) takes a rather long time (i.e. on the average between 2000ms and 5000ms (2 - 5 secs)).

Here is an excerpt from my profiling log

Time taken to open connection

```
2015-02-18 21:06:55,497 Opened connection at 18/02/2015 21:06:55 92.65 ms
```

Time taken to close / return connection

```
 Closed connection at 18/02/2015 21:07:01 2543.06 ms
```

Notice that opening the connection takes 92ms and closing the connection takes 2500ms.
BTW, these stats are provided my the EF framework itself i.e. by setting the Log property of the Database prop on the EF context i.e.

```
MyTestAppDbContext.Database.Log = Logger.Debug;
```

What I dont understand is why it is so fast to get a connection from the connection pool but it takes so long for EF to return the connection back to the pool (i.e. close the connection) and more importantly how to speed up the release/closing of the connection

This is quite important for me because the web app needs to be quite responsive and as I have to create the EF Dbcontext for every request, if EF adds an extra 2 - 5 secs overhead to just close / release a connection, it reduces the responsiveness of the app.

MyTestAppDbContext.cs

```
public partial class MyTestAppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }

    static MyTestAppDbContext()
    {
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<MyTestAppDbContext>(null);
    }

    public MyTestAppDbContext(ILogger logger)
        : base("Name=MyConnectionPoolConnectionString")
    {

            this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; 
            this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            Logger = logger;
            this.Database.Log = Logger.Debug;
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        Exception entityFrameworkExceptions = null;
        String exMsg = "";
        int result = 0;
        try
        {

            if (this.ChangeTracker.HasChanges())
            {
                // Get all Added/Deleted/Modified entities (not Unmodified or Detached)
                foreach (var ent in this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(p => p.State == EntityState.Added || p.State == EntityState.Deleted || p.State == EntityState.Modified))
                {

                    // For each changed record, log the activity performed
                   Logger.Debug("Detected Changes");
                }

                result = base.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            entityFrameworkExceptions = dbEx;
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    //System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                    exMsg += String.Format("\nProperty: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                    Logger.Debug(String.Format("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException dbEx)
        {
            entityFrameworkExceptions = dbEx;
            Logger.Debug(String.Format("Exception Message: {0}", dbEx.Message));
            Logger.Debug(String.Format("InnerException: {0}", dbEx.InnerException));
            Logger.Debug(String.Format("StackTrace: {0}", dbEx.StackTrace));
            Logger.Debug(String.Format("Call Stack: {0}", CommonUtils.GetCallStackAsString()));
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            entityFrameworkExceptions = ex;
            Logger.Debug(String.Format("Exception Message: {0}", ex.Message));
            Logger.Debug(String.Format("InnerException: {0}", ex.InnerException));
            Logger.Debug(String.Format("StackTrace: {0}", ex.StackTrace));
            Logger.Debug(String.Format("Call Stack: {0}", CommonUtils.GetCallStackAsString()));
        }
        if (entityFrameworkExceptions != null)
        {
            exMsg = exMsg + "\n" + entityFrameworkExceptions.Message + @"\n" + entityFrameworkExceptions.StackTrace + @"\n" + entityFrameworkExceptions.InnerException;
            entityFrameworkExceptions = new HttpException(500, @"Exception applying changes in PaceDBContext (i.e. Entity Framework)\n" + exMsg+"\n"+CommonUtils.GetCallStackAsString());

            throw entityFrameworkExceptions;

        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

IUnitOfWork.cs

```
public interface IUnitOfWork /*: IDisposable*/
{
   MyTestAppDbContext MyTestAppDbContext { get; set; }
   Exception Save();
}
```

UnitOfWork.cs

```
public class UnitOfWork :  IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
{
    private bool disposed = false;

    public MyTestAppDbContext MyTestAppDbContext {get; set;}
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }

    public Exception Save()
    {
        Exception entityFrameworkExceptions = null;
        String exMsg = "";//, callStackAsString = "";
        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("Saving Db Changes in UnitOfWork");
            MyTestAppDbContext.SaveChanges();
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("Finished saving Db Changes in UnitOfWork");
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            entityFrameworkExceptions = dbEx;
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {

                    exMsg += String.Format("\nProperty: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                    Logger.Debug(String.Format("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException dbEx)
        {
            entityFrameworkExceptions = dbEx;
            this.LogException(dbEx);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            entityFrameworkExceptions = ex;
            this.LogException(ex);
        }
        if (entityFrameworkExceptions != null)
        {
            exMsg = "\n" + entityFrameworkExceptions.Message + @"\n" + entityFrameworkExceptions.StackTrace + @"\n" + entityFrameworkExceptions.InnerException+"\n"+CommonUtils.GetCallStackAsString();
            entityFrameworkExceptions =  new HttpException(500, @"Exception applying changes in PaceDBContext (i.e. Entity Framework)\n" + exMsg);


            throw entityFrameworkExceptions;

        }

        return entityFrameworkExceptions;
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {

        this.Save();
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {

                MyTestAppDbContext.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void LogException(Exception ex){
        Logger.Debug(String.Format("Exception Message: {0}", ex.Message));
        Logger.Debug(String.Format("InnerException: {0}", ex.InnerException));
        Logger.Debug(String.Format("StackTrace: {0}", ex.StackTrace));
    }
}
```

UserRepository.cs

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{

    public IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; private set; }

    public UserRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        this.UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }


    public Users GetUserByUserId(string userId)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(userId)){
        var user = from u in UnitOfWork.MyTestAppDbContext.Users
                   where u.UserId.Trim().Equals(userId.Trim())
                   select u;
        return user.SingleOrDefault();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public string GetUserFullName(string userId)
    {
        string fullname = null;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
        {
            var user = (from u in UnitOfWork.MyTestAppDbContext.Users
                       where u.UserId.Trim().Equals(userId.Trim())
                       select u).SingleOrDefault();
            if (user != null)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(user.FirstName))
                    fullname += user.FirstName + " ";
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(user.LastName))
                    fullname += user.LastName;

            }
        }
        return fullname;
    }

    public long GetUserGroupId(string userId)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
        {
            var user = (from u in UnitOfWork.MyTestAppDbContext.Users
                       where u.UserId.Trim().Equals(userId.Trim())
                       select u).SingleOrDefault();
            if (user != null)
                return user.UserGroupId;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Code please. Pause the debugger while the connection is being closed. What's on the stack? Include external code.

Comment: @usr. Thanks for your reply. I have added the code. However I cant pause the code when connection is being closed because EF is responsible for that hence i cannot put a break point in the EF code. Also with regards to >'What's on the stack', I'm not sure which stack that you mean but if mean the call stack, then in that case, at the point of disposing, the  instance of the DbContext (i.e MyTestAppDbContext in my case) is on top of the stack.

Comment: VS has a pause button. Open/Close the connection in an infinite loop and pause the debugger. Report back.; Yes, I want to see the framework code that's on the call stack.

Comment: @usr, so if I'm what you are asking is that I step through the entity framework 6 code ??

Comment: No. You simply need to click that little pause button and look at the stack. Is there a problem with doing that?

Comment: @usr.  There is no problem with pausing the debugger. The problem is that I dont explicitly open the connection myself. EF is responsible for opening and closing/releasing/disposing of the connection. So unless you are asking me debug the EF code, there is no way I can know what happens when the connection is opened and closed by EF. To get a connection, all I do is create an instance of DbContext (i.e. an instance of MyTestAppDbContext ) and to close/release, I call Dispose. EF takes care of the details of opening and closing.

Comment: @usr, Hence I am a little miffed as to what you mean by "What's on the stack" the stack. From the point of view of my code, the last item on the stack when I close/release a connection is the call to the Dispose method. The actual details of the closing / release of the connection is then delegated EF and .NET. BTW, the debugger does not report what is happening in EF. It only reports whats in my code. I hope you understand what I mean??

Comment: We need to see what EF is doing that's taking so long. Clearly the last frame of yours is calling Dispose but something *inside* of Dispose is taking long. You can right-click the stack to "Show External Code". It will show EF and ADO.NET implementation details. Those might give a clue.

Comment: FWIW, the only significant thing `SqlConnection` does (irrespective of EF) is clean up any pending transactions and then issue an `exec sp_reset_connection` call to reset the connection back to its initial state for pool reuse. If there is no pending transaction on the connection, this is usually very fast. If there is a pending transaction, rolling back stuff takes a while.

Comment: @JeroenMostert. Thanks Jeroen. I think you are right. I think that SqlConnection is doing some like you say i.e. resetting connection and rollback etc. I've done a bit of probing and found that the SQL that is generated by EF in retrieving the entities in the affected area is a hugely massive statement with a large number of Joins. I would paste it but its so huge that I dont think that it would fit. Could it be that releasing the resources used for executing such massive statements could make releasing the connection take a huge amount of time??

Comment: That's improbable, because those queries should have finished by the time you call `.Close()`/`.Dispose()`, regardless of how much time/resources they take. As soon as the query is done, the resources are released on the server end; this is not postponed until the connection's closed -- unless you're doing something foolish like closing the connection while processing query results is still happening.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, I dont get my code involved in opening and closing/disposing the connection in any way. My code is exactly as I have displayed. I have updated the code with one of my repositories tha uses the UOW specified. Nothing interesting happens.The reason I was thinking it could be resources used to execute the query is that if I retrieve entities where there EF doesnt generate with so many Joins, the connection is released in super fast time (i.e. on the average about 14ms). However, the more joins generated, the longer it seems to release. Maybe thats a red herring but I'm not sure.